# Query not using the index

Tags: mysql

I have a query.

`SELECT id_id FROM videos_member ORDER BY date_id DESC LIMIT 0,30`

Here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `videos` (
  `id_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_id`),
  KEY `date_id` (`date_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

I keep getting this

```
id select_type table   type possible_keys key  key_len ref  rows  Extra
1  SIMPLE      videos  ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL 342   Using filesort
```

Why isn't is using the index?

Comment: Why do you think it should use the index? You are sorting in the opposite direction of the date_id index. In addition, you are accessing values not stored in that index.

Comment: @JRD I don't know anyhing about MySQL but I really hope indexes do not have a direction.

Comment: Think about that for a moment, an unordered index. Now, think of an unordered b-tree index. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JRD what is an unordered index? what is an unordered b-tree?  B-Trees are ordered.

Comment: Yes, that is my point, indexes have direction / order. In mysql, that direction is always ascending.

Comment: I still don't understand... If B-tree is ordered, I can traverse it in both ways, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table contains (or at least MySQL thinks it contains) 342 rows.  This is tiny and likely fits into a single block of physical storage, which means it can be read in a single read operation. Using the index would require at least two read operations.  So MySQL might be smart here and realize that reading the whole table at once is just more efficient than reading the index and then using it to access the table.
In other words if you insert more rows into the table the plan might change to using index.

Comment: i didnt undrstnd any o_O

Comment: Awesome! I kept adding rows. When I finally got to about row 900 it jumped over and started using the index.